# Permissions Changes from Google Cloud Functions Now Crash Server

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-functions, virtual-machine, identity-management

I'm suddenly having permission/connection problems with my node.js servers. I'm getting this error when starting any of my servers on my Virtual Machine:

```
MongoNetworkError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

This all worked fine until I messed around with adding a Google Cloud Function (which connects to my VM and starts my server via "node server.js"); I made adjustments to my IAM settings in doing so, and potentially made other changes I'm not fully recalling.

But the IAM changes were only to *expand* permissions in order to connect the function. I believe I'm forgetting something else I did to cause this and am at a loss. I did not change firewall settings, and I have confirmed that they still allow my proper ports. There are no outgoing restrictions on my firewall rules.

I did not make any changes to MongoDB settings, and I'm able to access the database just fine through Compass and from my local machine. It is only from the VM when I get this error.

When I remove my MongoDB code and restart the server, it does not crash but I cannot reach the external URL ("This site can't be reached").

Can you think of any other VM settings that could cause a sudden connection problem? I'm rather new at this and have gotten quite frustrated. Any suggestions on what to look into would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. At one point I restarted my GCP VM, and this changes the VM's external IP address. So I had to whitelist this new IP address for MongoDB, as well as change it in other locations.

You can reserve an IP address, which I will likely do now:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address